# Is it a good practice to use ES6 Symbol as unique ids?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Since `Symbol` is a unique and immutable data type, a common use case for `Symbol` is object properties. However, is it a good practice to use it as a unique id? For example:

```
        const list = [
            {id: Symbol()},
            {id: Symbol()}
        ]
```

Comment: It's not really what they're made for, and you could use any object. `{} != {} `

Comment: @lyschoening `{} !== {}` would not work if we want to maintain an immutable object.

Comment: @ChingTingWu: Object identity is immutable. If you want the objects themselves to be immutable, you could still freeze them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This depends entirely on your needs. If you only need them as an identifier in your own codebase, they're fine, certainly better than generating a random ID.

A major downside to using `Symbol()` though is that they aren't serializable. There isn't a way to share the value of `Symbol()` across networks/processes or save them to disk/databases.

For most cases it's probably better to use auto-incrementing IDs.